# Is Jstl tags caches the content

Tags: caching, jsp, jstl

Is jstl tags caches the content, tags like  caches content the between them.

I am using large jsp file, which caches the content between the jstl tags causing a big memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Only the `c:set` can store stuff in session or application scope, but you have the control fully in your hands.

Did you actually profile the memory leak? You might just have misinterpreted the profiler results.

Comment: This is an ancient bug and has been fixed.